# How to enable sshpass output to console

Tags: scp, sshpass

Using scp and interactively entering the password the file copy progress is sent to the console but there is no console output when using [sshpass](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) in a script to scp files.

```
$ sshpass -p [password] scp [file] root@[ip]:/[dir]
```

It seems sshpass is suppressing or hiding the console output of scp. Is there a way to enable the sshpass scp output to console?

Comment: I believe the best option is NOT to use `sshpass`. If you can, use pubkey authentication. If you need more freedom in control what is going on, you will have to write it as `expect` script, I guess.

Comment: This is an embedded target. sshpass is what is available for now.

Comment: Try out this link so that you may find [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188291/how-to-view-progress-with-sshpass-and-scp-in-linux]

Answer (score 8):

After

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

the file `send-files.exp` works as desired:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp -r $FILES $DEST
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "12345\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what was desired, but better than silence:

```
SSHPASS="12345" sshpass -e  scp -v -r $FILES $DEST 2>&1 | grep -v debug1
```

Note that `-e` is considered a bit safer than `-p`.

Output:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host servername, user username, command scp -v -t /src/path/dst_file.txt
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014
Authenticated to servername ([10.11.12.13]:22).
Sending file modes: C0600 590493 src_file.txt
Sink: C0600 590493 src_file.txt
Transferred: sent 594696, received 2600 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8920671.8, received 39001.0
```

Comment: why `-e` is considered a bit safer than `-p`?

Comment: @FarK `SSHPASS="12345" sshpass -e ps aux | grep sshpass` shows `sshpass -e ps aux` while `sshpass -p 12345 ps aux | grep sshpass` shows `sshpass -p zzzzz ps aux` and there is a short period of time that ps may show `-p 12345`. In addition, there is `history | grep shpass`, but commands preceded by a space are not saved in history...